# Constructor will run but not function from other file

Tags: c++, class, oop

Sorry new to C++ here and cannot find the answers that I am looking for anywhere.  I am trying to run the simplest possible program in C++ using OOP and multiple files.  If the `Vehicle` class has no `doSomething()` function in it, then the constructor prints out just fine.  When I add the function and call `car.doSomething()` it just gives me errors.  I have searched for days and can't find a working answer.

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehicle.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Vehicle car;

    car.doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Vehicle.cpp

```
#include "Vehicle.h"

Vehicle::Vehicle(){
    cout << "do something" << endl;
}

void doSomething(){
    cout << "do something else" << endl;
}
```

Vehicle.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vehicle{
    public:
        Vehicle();
        void doSomething();
};
```

Like I said, new to C++ and not sure how to fix this.  Thanks for any help.

Specs:

Codelite v10.0.0,

Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Error:  undefined reference to 'Vehicle::doSomething()'

Comment: And what is the error you are getting? Please, no using namespace std, especially not in headers.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Just like you have to do `Vehicle::` in front of the constructor name you need to do `Vehicle::` in front of he function name.

Comment: `When I add the function and call car.doSomething() it just gives me errors.` You forgot to include those errors in your question.

Comment: Voting to close as type.  `void doSomething()` -> `void Vehicle::soSomething()` when defining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't need to search for days; you only needed to read the chapter in your C++ book about defining member functions.

It goes like this:

```
void Vehicle::doSomething()
{
    cout << "do something else" << endl;
}
```

That `Vehicle::` is how the computer knows that this `doSomething` definition is for the class `Vehicle` (just like you did already with the constructor).

Without that, it's just an ordinary function. It doesn't matter that the file is called `Vehicle.cpp`; C++ doesn't really care about filenames. You could have all sorts of functions, variables, class definitions etc in that file, regardless of whether it were called `Vehicle.cpp` or `Stuff.cpp` or `Lightness4Eva.cpp` (that's not to say that your naming convention is ungood, though!).

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for the stupid question.  The tutorial I was watching didn't show that for some reason.

Comment: @LeeMorgan I strongly recommend learning C++ from a book, not from tutorials online.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have "unresolved" linker error in this case. It means error is not in runtime but in build time. Error message could prompt you that linker can't find Vehicle::doSomething(). This would point you that you didn't actually provide doSomething() function. Read error outputs, it helps to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

write doSomting() defination with class name as in .cpp file:

```
void Vehicle::doSomething()
{
cout << "do something else" << endl;
}
```